# image URL concern for CSS changer inside MVC controller

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have a Style controller that calls the StyleResolver action and it lets me switch between the css theme that will be used.

```
if (contractState == "FL" || contractState == "TX")
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/css";
    return Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/genesis-theme-flat/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css")));
}
else if (contractState == "AZ" || contractState == "CA" ||
    contractState == "GA" || contractState == "MO" ||
    contractState == "NM" || contractState == "SC" ||
    contractState == "UT")
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/css";
    return Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/nowcom-theme-flat/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css")));
}
```

Problem now is all the image related css inside the files like this two, results in a file path problem

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
    background: #ffffff url("images/ui-bg_flat_0_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #333;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
    background: #ececec url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_0_ececec_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #960000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

These images are inside these folder.

[image]

Resulting Path:

```
http://localhost:50402/Style/images/ui-bg_flat_0_ffffff_40x100.png 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:50402/Style/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_0_ececec_1x100.png 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems that after calling the Razor.Parse, the URL is not properly pointed to the *"Content/name-of-theme/images"* folder, but instead includes the calling Style controller.  What can i do to fix the path that is displayed to resolve the 404 issue for images?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by forcing the url path this way.

url(/content/genesis-theme-flat/images/ui-bg_glass_0_960000_1x400.png)